# DateTime column truncated when importing from csv into mysql using "Load Data Local Infile"

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to import a CSV into mysql, and my DateTime column doesn't import successfully. I found some other posts on this, but others posts either:

- [Require a separate script to do the import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904175/mysql-csv-import-date-entered-as-0000-00-00-000000-if-timestamp-has-millisec)
- Or deal with the problem of milliseconds being truncated (while my problem is the entire DateTime field gets imported as 00

This is what I'm doing:

```
Cmd.exe: echo "1","2011-11-08 17:33:33" > foo.csv

Mysql:

CREATE TABLE `foo` (SomeId INT, SomeDateTime DATETIME);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "c:\\tmp\\foo.csv"
INTO TABLE `foo`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

The row gets imported, but with `0000-00-00 00:00:00` instead of the date I entered. Is there a way to resolve this using the builtin `LOAD DATA` command - without creating a script to insert the data?

Comment: I tried the query with the same data and it worked as expected. I did use `ENCLOSED BY  '"'` instead of `ENCLOSED BY  '\"'`.

Comment: Not really answering your problem but for your info, MariaDB 5.3 will support **microseconds** in `DATETIME`, `TIME` and `TIMESTAMP` columns: http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=363

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had several problems in the import that were caused by extra whitespace.
My file was actually delimited by ", " (comma + space) - not by "," - and lines were terminated by `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Note in your CSV file you have to specify the DATETIME column LIKE '2012-01-01 8:00:00'
Try this: 
LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:/c:\tmp\foo.csv'  INTO TABLE foo FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(
  SomeId,
  SomeDateTime
);